# Cant seem to EDIT/MODIFY my php table by id

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_select_db("database", $con);

if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pleasework ORDER BY ID"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

?>

<form action="?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" id="form2" method="post" name="form2">
<img id="close1" src="X.png" width="25" height="25" onclick ="div_hide1()">
<h2><font size="6">Please change existing data</font></h2>
<hr>
<br> 

     <font color="yellow">Change Name to: </font><input type="text" name="New" value="<?php echo $row['Name'];?>"/><br><br>
      <font color="yellow"> Change Cause to: </font> <input type="text" name="New1" value="<?php echo $row['Cause'];?>"/><br><br>
     <font color="yellow">Change Symptom to:  </font><input type="text" name="New2" value="<?php echo $row['Symptom'];?>"/><br><br>
      <font color="yellow"> Change Gene_affected to:  </font><input type="text" name="New3"value="<?php echo $row['Gene_affected'];?>" /><br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['ID'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="clicked(event)" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Name= '$_POST[New]' WHERE ID='$_POST[id]'");
mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Cause= '$_POST[New1]' WHERE     ID='$_POST[id]'");
mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Symptom= '$_POST[New2]' WHERE ID='$_POST[id]'");
mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Gene_affected= '$_POST[New3]' WHERE ID='$_POST[id]'");
echo "Change Successful<br>" ;
header("Location: databse.php");
mysql_close($con);
} 
else {}
?>
```

This is my php file.

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                 echo "<TR>";
             echo "<TD>" . $row['ID'] ."</TD>";
             echo "<TD>" . $row['Name'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>";
             echo "<TD>" . $row['Cause'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>";
             echo "<TD>" . $row['Symptom']. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>"; 
             echo "<TD>" . $row['Gene_affected'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;        </TD>";     
  echo "<TD><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row['ID'] ."\"><font     color='red'>Delete row</font></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>";

  echo "<TD><a href=\"edit.php?id=" . $row['ID'] ."\"><font     color='red'>modify</font></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>";
             echo "</TR>";
            }
```

And this is the section which has a modify button that links to the edit.php file. The error here is that is doesnt bring over the values in the table to the editing page and then submitting the form doesnt work too. help please

Comment: don't use  mysql_* its deprecated now

Comment: i have no choice its for a project :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears a bit confused.

First of all, why to put the modify routine after output the form? Especially since after modify you send the `header` function, that fails if previously there are some output.

Note also a typo: you forgot to properly open the php tag in the `form` declaration. Change-it in this way:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" id="form2" method="post" name="form2">
```

The main problem is that you check if the `$_POST[submit]` if set, but this is not set, due to the absence of attribute `name`.

Change it in this way:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="clicked(event)" />
```

Now your script should work (I don't have tested the sql).

Please also note that your `UPDATE` routine is redundant: you can reduce the 4 statement to only one in this way:

```
 $result = mysql_query
 (
    "UPDATE pleasework SET Name='{$_POST[New]}', Cause='{$_POST[New1]}', Symptom='{$_POST[New2]}', Gene_affected='{$_POST[New3]}' WHERE ID={$_POST[id]}"
 );
```

**About PHP Original MySQL API:**

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` deprecated, so try to use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Simple way:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $result = mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework 
                            SET Name='".$_POST['New']."',
                                Cause='".$_POST['New1']."',
                                Symptom='".$_POST['New2']."',
                                Gene_affected='".$_POST['New3']."' 
                            WHERE ID=".$_POST['id'].");

     if($result ){ 
        echo "Change Successful<br>" ;
        header("Location: databse.php");
     }
     mysql_close($con);
}
```

YOUR PHP:

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {      $spaces = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<TR>";
        echo "<TD>" . $row['ID'] ."</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $row['Name'] . $spaces."</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $row['Cause'] . $spaces."</TD>";
        echo "<TD>" . $row['Symptom']. $spaces."</TD>"; 
        echo "<TD>" . $row['Gene_affected'] . $spaces."</TD>";     
        echo "<TD><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['ID'] ."'>";
        echo "<font  color='red'>Delete row</font></a>".$spaces."</TD>";

        echo "<TD><a href='edit.php?id=" . $row['ID'] ."'>";
        echo "<font color='red'>modify</font></a>".$spaces."</TD>";
      echo "</TR>";
  }
```