# $row error keeps saying undefined? I cant find the mistake

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, localhost

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }




mysql_select_db("database", $con);
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pleasework WHERE ID= $_GET[id]");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
if(isset($_POST['New']))
{
    $New= $_POST['New'];
    $id= $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE pleasework SET Name = '$New' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("could not update" . mysql_error);

}

?>

 <form action="edit.php" id="form2" method="post" name="form2">
<img id="close1" src="X.png" width="25" height="25" onclick ="div_hide1()">
<h2><font size="6">Please change existing data</font></h2>
<hr>

     <font color="yellow">Change Name to: </font><input type="text" name="New" value="<?php echo $row['Name'];?>"/><br><br>
      <font color="yellow"> Change Cause to: </font> <input type="text" name="New1" value="<?php echo $row['Cause'];?>"/><br><br>
 <font color="yellow">Change Symptom to:  </font><input type="text" name="New2" value="<?php echo $row['Symptom'];?>"/><br><br>
      <font color="yellow"> Change Gene_affected to:  </font><input type="text" name="New3"value="<?php echo $row['Gene_affected'];?>" /><br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="clicked(event)" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $u = "(UPDATE pleasework SET Name='$_POST[New]' , '$_POST[New1]' ,     '$_POST[New2]' , '$_POST[New3]'  WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
    mysql_query($u) or die(mysql_error());

    echo"User has been modified";
    header("Location: databse.php");
} 

?>
```

This error keeps popping up whenever I click submit on my `edit.php` file. I thought I already declared `$row`?

The same error goes on for all the input types...

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: row in <b>E:\XAMPP\htdocs\database\edit.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
```

Comment: You use `$row` always in your HTML, but it is only defined if the page is requested with `?id=...`. Perhaps add a `if ( $_REQUEST['id'] ) { }` around the `<form>` (or `if ( $row )` and set `$row` to `null` in the top of the page).

Comment: `$row` exists only when `GET[id]` set.

Comment: so what should i do to my codes now? please tell me

Comment: if the code is working right. then block the error at line 34

Comment: it is working fine only at all the input types. so line 34,35,36,37 has error with $row. how do i block the error?

Comment: This for one thing `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` will never happen. Not for what you posted anyway and we've no way to know what this function does `onclick="clicked(event)"`. Nice SQL injection by the way.

Comment: take it up with the guy who gave you an answer below. I doubt very much that will work, but hey; *try it*.

Comment: didn't you post this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114395/cant-seem-to-edit-modify-my-php-table-by-id

Comment: and you're outputting before header.

Comment: use `@$row` to block the error (notice the '@')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 <?php
    $submit=isset($_POST['submit']);
    $id=isset($_POST['id']);

    if($submit)
    {
        $New= $_POST['New'];
        $id= $_POST['id'];
      //insert db configurations
        $sql = "UPDATE pleasework SET Name = '$New' WHERE id='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("could not update" . mysql_error);
    }
    else if($id)
    {
    $id= $_POST['id'];
      //insert db configurations
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pleasework WHERE ID= $_GET[id]");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>

     <form action="edit.php" id="form2" method="post" name="form2">
    <img id="close1" src="X.png" width="25" height="25" onclick ="div_hide1()">
    <h2><font size="6">Please change existing data</font></h2>
    <hr>

         <font color="yellow">Change Name to: </font><input type="text" name="New" value="<?php echo $row['Name'];?>"/><br><br>
          <font color="yellow"> Change Cause to: </font> <input type="text" name="New1" value="<?php echo $row['Cause'];?>"/><br><br>
     <font color="yellow">Change Symptom to:  </font><input type="text" name="New2" value="<?php echo $row['Symptom'];?>"/><br><br>
          <font color="yellow"> Change Gene_affected to:  </font><input type="text" name="New3"value="<?php echo $row['Gene_affected'];?>" /><br><br>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
        <input type="submit" onclick="clicked(event)" />
    </form>

    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    echo"anything";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: care to give an explanation for everyone here? nice SQL injection too.